# Checking the value of a cvMat element when during iteration

Tags: opencv, image-processing, visual-c++-2010

I'm using CV_MAT_ELEM to access the value of a cvmat without any problem, but when I use it in a for loop it gives me an error ( assertion failed ).

```
 for (int i=0;i<=direction->cols;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<=direction->rows;j++){
         if ((CV_MAT_ELEM(*direction,float,i,j)<22.0) ) {
             CV_MAT_ELEM(*direction,float,i,j)=0;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: just a sidenote: the old c-api is no more developed since 5 years, they switched over to c++, and so should you ..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access some pixels that are not within the image's range.

Try to change

```
 for (int i=0;i<=direction->cols;i++){
               ^^
     for(int j=0;j<=direction->rows;j++){
                  ^^
```

to

```
 for (int i=0;i<direction->cols;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<direction->rows;j++){
```

---

**P.S.:** As @berak commented, you are still using old OpenCV API, i.e. using `IplImage` and `CV_MAT_ELEM`. Try to use the new API, i.e. `Mat` and `at()` correspondingly.

Comment: it didnt make a difference.

Comment: @shahd How is your `direction` defined? Please share its details.